# Is there a GUI/Painting Library for C++ and MacOS

Tags: c++, graphic-design

I have started to learn C++. (Which might be a mistake)
Unfortunately, I need an easy to use drawing library like Javas Swing or FX to draw efficiently.

I understand nothing about rendering etc.
OpenGL seems to be deprecated and I feel like that is the wrong way to go.

Therefore, I need a beginner-friendly, well-documented Library for C++.
Maybe this an Oxymoron.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of May 2019 there is Apple's C drawing library, Quartz 2D. I have used this successfully in a pure C++ application for macOS (no Objective-C). I made it using Xcode. The frameworks needed to draw an image and  export it as a file on disk (TIFF format for me) are CoreFoundation, CoreServices, CoreGraphics, ImageIO.

The Quartz 2D programming guide is here: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html.

Unfortunately this guide is marked as no longer being updated; it was last modified in 2017. I hope Apple are not discontinuing Quartz 2D.

I'm not sure how beginner-friendly it is - I found it a bit tedious to work out how to set up the drawing context and so on - but the guide is good.